# How can I query the class which the schedule job will call

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled

I am trying to get the name of the schedule / batch classes called by the schedule job

Trying this

```
select Id,CronJobDetailId,CronJobDetail.Name,
       NextFireTime,PreviousFireTime,State,StartTime,EndTime,CronExpression,
       TimeZoneSidKey,OwnerId,TimesTriggered 
from CronTrigger 
where CronJobDetail.Name = 'Assetupdates'
```

The job was scheduled via execute anonymous and given a very undescriptive name

Thanks

Answer (score 28):

Ok, found what I was looking for

```
select ApexClassId, Id, JobItemsProcessed, JobType, 
       Status, NumberOfErrors, MethodName 
from AsyncApexJob  
where JobType in ('BatchApexWorker','ScheduledApex')
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this myself. Not sure if my understanding is correct, but I believe querying "AsyncApexJob" will only give details on a job that has already been executed/entered the queue. Is there any way to get the class name from a scheduled job that has not been executed yet? Annoyingly, there doesn't seem to be a class ID or class name field in CronJobDetail...

Comment: AsyncApexJob also has entries for Scheduled Jobs which are not fired yet. They will be in 'Queued' status. As you said, based on current datamodel it is not possible correlate Job Name to Apex Class name.

Comment: I tested the following query (showing the class name and namespace instead of class id): 
    select ApexClass.Name, ApexClass.Namespaceprefix, Id, JobItemsProcessed, JobType, 
       Status, NumberOfErrors, MethodName 
    from AsyncApexJob  
    where JobType in ('BatchApexWorker','ScheduledApex')

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there isn't any direct link between the `CronTrigger` table and the related apex class id (at least that they expose). See the these [two](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lHfrQAE) [ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ah8QAA) to vote it up. That said you've got some options.

### Option 1 - Setup Menu

Sometimes you can get it from the setup. Go to setup->monitor->jobs->scheduled jobs, and you'll see a list of all scheduled jobs. For apex classes that were scheduled through the 'Schedule Apex' button in setup->develop->apex classes, you'll see a 'Manage' link next to the job. Click that and you'll see the class name associated with that job.

### Option 2 - Test Delete Schedulable Classes

However, it turns out the metadata api is kind enough to return the id of the CronTrigger records associated with an apex class if you try and delete it.

First you'll need to get a list of all schedulable apex classes then you org and then try and delete them with the metadata api. If say there was just one, `MySchedulableClass` you would you would have the following `destructiveChanges.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MySchedulableClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

If you do a test deployment, you'll get an error like the following which includes the crontrigger ids (they start with `08e`)

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/yourname/ant/sfse/build.xml:95: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/yourname/ant/sfse/build.xml:55: 
*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
Request ID: 0AfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

All Component Failures:
1.  classes/MySchedulableClass.cls -- Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.  Remove the usage and try again. : Scheduled Jobs - 08eXXXXXXXXXXXX. This Schedulable class is in use. : Apex Class.

*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
```

Then it's just a matter of searching those errors for the id of the particular `CronTrigger` you're interested in and you'll have your answer.

**CAVEAT** I expect this approach won't work for schedulable classes that are part of a managed package since you won't be able to delete those with the metadata api, but who knows, worth trying.

### Option 3 - Correlate with `AsyncApexJob` Table

Based on @michael's answer. In most cases schedulable jobs will start a batch job. If that's the case you can look at the last fired date for the scheduled jobs list and try and find the corresponding job in the `AsyncApexJob` table based on the created date for the `AsyncApexJob`, then you can inspect the `ApexClassId` column.

Comment: @michael_gill, this is really what you were looking for right?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Scott,
you can also use the field `ApexClass.name` in your query:

```
SELECT ApexClassId,
       ApexClass.name,
       Id,
       JobItemsProcessed,
       JobType,
       Status,
       NumberOfErrors,
       MethodName
FROM AsyncApexJob
WHERE JobType in ('BatchApexWorker',
                  'ScheduledApex')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<AsyncApexJob> listfetched = [select ApexClass.Name, Id, JobItemsProcessed, JobType, Status, NumberOfErrors, MethodName , CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name from AsyncApexJob where JobType in ('BatchApexWorker', 'ScheduledApex')];
for(AsyncApexJob a : listfetched)
{
    System.debug(a.ApexClass.Name +' >>> '+a.CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since API [v53.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) you can do the following to get the Apex class name related to a **BatchApex** and **ScheduledApex** job :

```
SELECT Id, ApexClass.Name, MethodName, JobType, Status, LastProcessed, JobItemsProcessed, NumberOfErrors
FROM AsyncApexJob
WHERE CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name = 'Name of your scheduled/batch job'
AND JobType in ('BatchApexWorker', 'ScheduledApex')
```

Be aware that it does not work through api (with navigator extensions for example) only in dev console or apex code.