# How can I delete/abort all scheduled jobs for a particular apex class?

Tags: apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I need to delete/abort all schedule jobs associated with a particular apex class. There are nearly 1500 scheduled jobs in my org. Any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: reference -> https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BWyKIAW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I query the class which the schedule job will call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47065/how-can-i-query-the-class-which-the-schedule-job-will-call)

Comment: Neither of those links actually answer *this* question, although they're related.

Comment: Hi @vinoth, welcome to SFSE. Pro-tip, you'll get a better response if you include details about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Good news, this is possible. As discussed in [How can I query the class which the schedule job will call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47065/594) the `CronTrigger` and `CronJobDetail` tables which underly schedule jobs have a gaping hole in that they don't include details about the associated apex class id (at least that they expose). See the these [two](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lHfrQAE) [ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ah8QAA) to vote it up.

In some cases if you go to setup->monitor->jobs->scheduled jobs, and you'll see a list of all scheduled jobs. For apex classes that were scheduled through the 'Schedule Apex' button in setup->develop->apex classes, you'll see a 'Manage' link next to the job. Click that and you'll see the class name associated with that job.

However, it turns out the metadata api is kind enough to return the id of the `CronTrigger` records associated with an apex class if you try and delete it.

So let's say your class is `MySchedulableClass` you would have the following `destructiveChanges.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MySchedulableClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

If you do a test deployment, you'll get an error like the following which includes the crontrigger ids (they start with `08e`)

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/yourname/ant/sfse/build.xml:95: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/yourname/ant/sfse/build.xml:55: 
*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
Request ID: 0AfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

All Component Failures:
1.  classes/MySchedulableClass.cls -- Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.  Remove the usage and try again. : Scheduled Jobs - 08eXXXXXXXXXXXX. This Schedulable class is in use. : Apex Class.

*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
```

Once you have those ids you can use the `System.abortJob` method to cancel each id returned

```
System.abortJob('08eXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Comment: pretty clever; I suggest slightly editing your answer to make it more obvious what the two ideas are via the hyperlinks.

Comment: @cropredy it's community editable ;-P

fyi, i submitted a request to merge the two of those ideas, so hopefully that won't matter