# Schedule class from the CronTrigger?

Tags: scheduled-apex, cron

I have a requirement where I need give user an option to schedule a batch in a custom lightning configuration page. I can able to do it when we create a single schedule for a particular Batch by using the JobName(It should be unique per Schedule class) like below,

```
List<CronTrigger> cronList = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = sampleJob AND State = 'DELETED'];

    if (cronList.isEmpty()) {
        Process_SCH ProcessScheduler = new Process_SCH(startDateDuration, endDateDuration, selectedDate);
        String nextFireTime = String.valueOf(selectedDate.second()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.minute()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.hour()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.day()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.month()) + '  ? ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.year());
        System.schedule(jobName, nextFireTime, ProcessScheduler);
        return 'Successfully Start the Job';
    } else if (cronList.size() == 1) {
        System.abortJob(cronList[0].Id);
        Process_SCH taxRcptProcessScheduler = new Process_SCH(startDateDuration, endDateDuration, selectedDate);
        String nextFireTime = String.valueOf(selectedDate.second()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.minute()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.hour()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.day()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.month()) + '  ? ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.year());
        System.schedule(jobName, nextFireTime, ProcessScheduler);
        return 'Successfully Start the Job';
    } else {
        return 'There is a Job already schedule for the Batch and the Id of the Job is ' + cronList[0].Id;
    }
```

But there is a chain request came that we need to allow the user to create multiple schedule for the particular Batch/SCH. IS there any way to get the SCH class from the CronTrigger class? If so I can able to do it or else any other suggestion to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: realted possibly of use to you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47065/how-can-i-query-the-class-which-the-schedule-job-will-call

Comment: If I am not wrong this question is something else but maybe the subject is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement above is to allow the user to schedule multiple schedule for a particular Schedule class. The limitation here is we can't get the Class Name and the CronTrigger details from the CronTrigger object and also there is no link between CronTrigger and AsyncApexJob to combine information from both to do what you need as far as I know. Here what I did was I scheduled the Batch with the name which I construct using the required parameters with the 'Process-sch-' prefix and achieve the requirement like below,

```
String keyWord = '%Process-sch-'%';
String jobName = 'Process-sch-' + startDateDuration.format() + '-' + endDateDuration.format();

    List<CronTrigger> cronList = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name, State FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name =: jobName];

    if (cronList.isEmpty()) {
        Process_SCH ProcessScheduler = new Process_SCH(startDateDuration, endDateDuration, selectedDate);
        String nextFireTime = String.valueOf(selectedDate.second()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.minute()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.hour()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.day()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.month()) + '  ? ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.year());
        System.schedule(jobName, nextFireTime, (Schedulable) ProcessScheduler);
        return 'Successfully Start the Job';
    } else if (cronList.size() == 1 && cronList[0].State == 'DELETED') {
        System.abortJob(cronList[0].Id);
        Process_SCH ProcessScheduler = new Process_SCH(startDateDuration, endDateDuration, selectedDate);
        String nextFireTime = String.valueOf(selectedDate.second()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.minute()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.hour()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.day()) + ' ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.month()) + '  ? ' + String.valueOf(selectedDate.year());
        System.schedule(jobName, nextFireTime, ProcessScheduler);
        return 'Successfully Start the Job';
    } else if (cronList.size() == 1 && cronList[0].State != 'DELETED'){
        return 'The Apex job named " ' + jobName + ' " is already scheduled for execution.';
    }
```

If you need to query only the needed Job Details for this particular schedule(Batch Class) you can query like below,

```
List<CronTrigger> cronJob = [SELECT Id, State, CronJobDetail.Name, NextFireTime, StartTime, TimesTriggered FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE :keyWord]
```